# Sum old variable with new variable

Tags: java, math, sum

I have an Adapter that points to items that have a "Time" attribute.
If the user taps a button on one item and on another I'd need both Time values to be summed. I can't achieve this.

I've tried stuff like `time += time`, separate those values etc

This was the last thing I was trying. Yeah it makes no sense but idk, nothing had worked.

```
 [...]
  add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GetTime(gameItem.getTime());

            }
        });
    }

    private int GetTime(int timeplayed) {
        time += timeplayed;

        return time;
    }
```

Which should have been like at the start there is an empty variable time.
timeplayed is added to it and is returned as time.
So eveytime you tap the button the timeplayed gets added and returned as time

Actually tho, instead of summing the old variable with the new one it either does just a 0 + number or it sums the new variable with itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you said it sounds to me that the field value is being altered or actually not initialized at all before you get to actually do your mathematical operations on it. So the answer to your question is simple: *make sure the value of the field is not changed before your code reaches the `private int GetTime(int timeplayed)` method.*

In any case your code absolutely should work as the syntax of the operation is correct. `time += timeplayed` is equivalent to `time = time + timeplayed`. I can't see the rest of your code so I can't really say whats going on underneath the hood but if you are willing to share the rest of your code, pretty much anywhere the time variable is being altered *(including the place where it's being actually initialized)* I could help you out further.

But first you need to make sure the variable has an expected value (not the same as `timeplayed` and not 0). You can do this through debugging either with using breakpoints or logging the value in console before the operation gets executed.

Hope this helps, let me know how it goes.